# DISTINCT select statement but return rows in original sort order?

Tags: t-sql

I have a list of Attributes of which there are duplicates.
I need to return a distinct list of the attributes but preserving the original sort order. So in y example below I need to return...

Zebra
Apple
Ball

Any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Attributes TABLE (ID INT, Attribute VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Attributes (ID, Attribute) VALUES (1, 'Zebra'),(2, 'Apple'),(3, 'Ball'),(4, 'Zebra'),(5, 'Ball')
SELECT DISTINCT Attribute FROM @Attributes
```

Comment: By "original sort order", do you mean in order of the `ID` column? If so, then you need to define the rule for sorting when there are duplicates. For example, in your data "Zebra" appears before "Apple", as well as after "Apple", in ID order. So when you get the distinct values, should it appear before or after "Apple"? In any case, a pattern that should get you started based on the expected output in your question would be `select Attribute from @Attributes group by Attribute order by min(ID);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I did not consider grouping to resolve this!
Thanks to @allmhuran who made a suggestion that works perfectly.

```
select Attribute from @Attributes group by Attribute order by min(ID);
```